# How can I configure Spring Boot, Spring JPA, Spring Test, and Hibernate to create, use, and drop a given PostgreSQL schema?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How can I configure [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/), [Spring Test](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html), and [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) to create, use, and drop a given [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) schema for a unit test which saves and retrieves an object?

Before the test starts Spring Test should create the database schema for the test.  Each test method should run within a single transaction and after it finishes, the test method should roll back all database operations.  At the end of all test methods, the test should drop the schema.

In its present form, `AccountRepositoryTest` passes, but creates table `account` in schema `public` instead of creating table `account` in new schema `springboot`.

Configuration:

- Spring Boot 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
- Spring Data JPA 1.9.0.RELEASE
- Spring Test 4.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
- Hibernate 4.3.11.Final
- PostgreSQL 9.5.4

**AccountRepositoryTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(Application.class)
public class AccountRepositoryTest {
    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountRepositoryTest.class);

    @Autowired
    AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Test
    public void testSaveAccount() {
        final Account newAccount = accountRepository.save(new Account("123", "Derek Mahar", 500.00));
        final Account readAccount = accountRepository.findOne(newAccount.getId());
        logger.info("New account UUID={}", newAccount.getId());
        assertEquals(newAccount.getBalance(), readAccount.getBalance(), 0.001);
        assertEquals(newAccount.getNumber(), readAccount.getNumber());
        assertEquals(newAccount.getOwner(), readAccount.getOwner());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindByNumber() {
        final Account newAccount = accountRepository.save(new Account("456", "Steve Balmer", 500.00));
        final Account readAccount = accountRepository.findByNumber(newAccount.getNumber());
        logger.info("New account UUID={}", newAccount.getId());
        assertEquals(newAccount.getBalance(), readAccount.getBalance(), 0.001);
        assertEquals(newAccount.getNumber(), readAccount.getNumber());
        assertEquals(newAccount.getOwner(), readAccount.getOwner());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindByOwner() {
        final Account newAccount = accountRepository.save(new Account("789", "Bill Gates", 500.00));
        final Account readAccount = accountRepository.findByNumber(newAccount.getNumber());
        logger.info("New account UUID={}", newAccount.getId());
        assertEquals(newAccount.getBalance(), readAccount.getBalance(), 0.001);
        assertEquals(newAccount.getNumber(), readAccount.getNumber());
        assertEquals(newAccount.getOwner(), readAccount.getOwner());
    }
}
```

**AccountRepository.java**

```
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, UUID> {
    Account findByNumber(String number);
    Account findByOwner(String owner);
}
```

**Account.java**

```
@Entity
public class Account implements Serializable {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private double balance;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column
    private UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String number;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String owner;

    public Account(String number, String owner, double balance) {
        this.number = number;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public Account() {
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:springboot
spring.datasource.username=springboot
spring.datasource.password=springboot
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.schema=springboot
spring.datasource.initialize=true

spring.jpa.database=springboot
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Comment: I learned that applying annotation `@Transactional` (see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-tx-enabling-transactions) to a test class instructs Spring to run each test method within a transaction and roll back all database operations that that the test performs.  However, I still haven't determined how to configure Spring to create a separate schema to contain the database artifacts that the test creates.

Comment: Adding `CREATE SCHEMA springboot` to `schema.sql` (see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-intialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc) created schema `springboot`, but did not delete the schema when the unit test completed.  Consequently, the test fails the next time it runs because schema `springboot` still exists.  How can I force Spring to drop the schema after the test completes?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to include `CREATE SCHEMA` in the same transaction as the test so that the whole schema is discarded during the rollback at the end of the test.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to use the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` Spring Boot property.  Include it in `application-test.properties` (or `application-test.yaml`, as the case may be) and set its value to `create-drop` (for example, `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`.  More details are available in the [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html).

However, I would recommend using an in-memory database for running the tests as you will not run the risk of pointing the tests to an actual database schema, the tests will run faster and you will be able to run continuous integration builds on third-party systems like Travis-CI or Shippable.

Comment: Already have property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` in `application.properties` (see question).

Comment: Before using PostgreSQL, I successfully "solved" this problem using HSQLDB and MySQL.  As you mention, when using in-memory database HSQLDB, at the conclusion of the test, Spring Boot and/or Spring Data JPA deletes the database schema automatically, including the schema.  I observed similar behaviour using MySQL.  PostgreSQL doesn't behave this way, though.

Comment: I looked at your post a couple of times again and found that your configuration is correct.  I have not seen that problem with the apps I have.  I regularly use Postgres on Heroku and have not seen this problem at all with the tests with custom schemas.  Unfortunately, I only use in-memory databases for development and testing so I cannot verify your configuration locally.  I will give your sample code a try with one of my Heroku apps once I get some time.

Comment: When I commit the "real" tests, I'll likely also use in-memory database HSQLDB, unless it does not support a UUID column type.

Comment: Just confirmed that my test methods pass when using HSQLDB instead of PostgreSQL, so HSQLDB does work with a UUID column type and generator.